# How to I connect Button Action to Tabbar Viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am new to iPhone development. I am developing a `TabBarViewcontroller` App (iPhone and iPad) and in that I've created one `LoginViewController` and a Button Action.
My expectation is after clicking that Button, the control  will move from `LoginViewController` to `TabBarViewController`.  In this `TabBarViewcontroller` I have 5 Tabbar (items) ViewControllers.
Is it possible?

If you can, please share your ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, take `UINavigationController` and `UITabbarController` in your `MainWindow.xib` and bind `IBOutlet` to respective fields.. ans set `LoginViewController` as rootViewController of your `UINavigationController`..

Then in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method write this..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    [self.window setRootViewController:navController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    
    return YES;
}
```

Now create other method in `AppDelegate.m` like this..

```
-(void)loadApplication
{
    [navController pushViewController:tabbarController animated:NO];
}
```

On your Login button action.. call this method as follows..

```
-(IBAction)btnLoginTapped:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [appDelegate loadApplication];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

So in button action try following codes

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

Comment: @Ramesh.GR is it solving your problem?

Answer (score 5):

use this method to add tabbar from any other view..

```
    -(void)addTabBarControllerInwindow 
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.window cache:YES];

        [self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

put this method in `AppDelegate.m` file and in any viewController e.g. in LoginView Controller
 when you want to add tabbar then declare object of delegate and call this method like bellow..

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [appDelegate addTabBarControllerInwindow];
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer..I used this code it's working for me...AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

Comment: @Ramesh.GR always wel-come mate.. :) upvote or accpet answer if its useful to you..

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for multiple VC in a single project. So declare and initialise  a VC for loginVC and otherVCs(for tabbar) in appDelegate and after login successful call the following function.

On launch make LoginVC as RootViewController

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{// declare LoginVC and make it rootViewController
 self.window.rootViewController = self._loginVCObj;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

`#pragma mark- Continue to next screen after successful Login`

```
-(void) continueToNextView
{   // Handle UI after Login like.
 [_loginVCObj._indicator stopAnimating];
    [_loginVCObj._loginButton setEnabled:YES];
//add the VC to the tabbar 
    self._tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.navigationControllerList,_favItemListNavObj, _toDoHereVC, _settingNavObj, nil]; 
// make tabbar as rootViewController
     self.window.rootViewController = self._tabBarController;
}
```

Comment: Tnx for your Answer...I used this code it's working..for me.. AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

Comment: @Ramesh.GR Good to hear that. Enjoy.